# Does Novice Power let you retrain your Paragon Path encounter power?

Tags: dnd-4e, multi-classing

The *Novice Power* feat reads

> You can swap one encounter attack power you know for one encounter attack power of the same level or lower from the class you multiclassed into.
>
> Note: If you have no encounter attack powers, this feat grants no benefit to you.

I have a Slayer multiclassed into Barbarian with the Draeven Marauder paragon path. As a Slayer the only encounter powers he has is multiple uses of Power Strike, but power strike has no level, and so cannot be swapped out with *Novice Power*.

Draeven Marauder however provides a level 11 encounter attack power, and presumably should be swappable but the character builder does not let me.

What is correct here?

Comment: What level are you?

Comment: What level? 14th.

Comment: Looks like what I am attempting here is a 2-feat trick: Reserve Maneuver will teach me an encounter attack power, and as long as the level is right, I can choose the RM power in place of the PP power. And the character builder (as well as the "Swapping Powers" RC text on p90, though not the "Power-Swap Feats" PH p209 text) allows the RM power to be swapped out for a power from my multiclass, by using the Novice Power feat. Is it worth it? Dunno....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No

Rules Compendium, page 90:

> **Swapping Powers**
>   Some game features, particularily feats, give you the option of swapping one of your adventurer's powers for a different power. This option provides a way to customize your adventurer and to experiment with different abilities.
>   [...] Unless instructed otherwise, you cannot replace powers that your character gained from a paragon path or an epic destiny.

Also, Player's Handbook, page 209

> **Power-Swap Feats**
>   The Novice Power, Acolyte Power, and Adept Power
>   feats give you access to a power from the class for
>   which you took a class-specific multiclass feat. That
>   power replaces a power you would normally have
>   from your primary class. When you take one of these
>   power-swap feats, you give up a power of your choice
>   from your primary class and replace it with a power of
>   the same level or lower from the class you have multiclassed
>   in.

Comment: AH, hard rulings.  It didn't seem to make sense before, but now that I know there's a rule for it specifically...

Comment: @CrystalBlue: It may seem restrictive at first, but one should remember that paragon paths and epic destinies are defined by their abilities and powers. Imagine e.g. a [War Wizard of Cormyr](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=66) that is unable to create the signature attack [Lightning Ripple](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1838).

Comment: Well, I agree with you.  That's why it didn't make sense when I saw that and thought 'Wait...I guess you could, by the rules, swap it out'.  I was actually looking for that ruling but didn't run across it.

Comment: @SimonWithers Uh! I always forgot that on SE it's not impolite to edit other people's answers. :) Also, arotter's reference to RC already encompassed the PHB case (that's the reason I deleted my answer). Anyway, you did well in adding as many references as possible to strengthen the concept.