# Can I replace a Paragon Power?

Tags: dnd-4e

Can I replace Kensei encounter attack power `Masterstroke` at level 13 or higher? I mean replacing, not retraining.

Comment: related (but not exact dupe) http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12722/does-novice-power-let-you-retrain-your-paragon-path-encounter-power

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

When replacing encounter powers with new ones in paragon and epic tiers, you can only replace encounter powers from your class, so an encounter power from your paragon path cannot be chosen for replacement.

Nor can you retrain the power.

You can replace it with a lower level encounter power from your class, via the Reserve Maneuver<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=512)</sup> feat.